# Why is the Styles panel showing only css files and not .scss files?

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools, compass

I need the Styles panel to show`.scss` styles. Right now, if I right-click an element, only `.css` styles are shown. I actually was able to show `.scss` files about an hour ago(lol) but then something changed suddenly and I can't go back to that setup anymore. This [tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-source-maps-chrome-magic) is what I followed and everything still seems to be the same except that I can't see `.scss` files in the Styles panel anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to delete .sass-cache dir and config.rb file from the "watched" dir and setup compass and chrome dev tools again. Not sure what happened though but everything is working now.